# CakePHP/Jenkins/Phing - Run all unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, continuous-integration, jenkins, phing

I'm in the middle of my first ever stab at setting up Jenkins to build and run unit tests /code coverage with my CakePHP project. So far I have successfully got Jenkins fetching and building automatically from my BitBucket repository - a small victory in itself.

Next thing I want to happen is for the unit tests to run and code coverage reports to be populated.

Here is my build.xml, which is being executed in Jenkins with the (only) build command `phing -f $WORKSPACE/build.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Consumer Love" default="phpunit">
    <target name="phpunit">
        <exec command="cake test app --coverage-clover logs/reports/clover.xml"></exec>
    </target>
</project>
```

I think the issue is that when you run `cake test app` it asks for a prompt of which specific tests you want to run, I have been unable to figure out a method to run *all* of my CakePHP app unit tests.

Comment: It looks like there will be built-in support for this (again?) in CakePHP 2.5: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/2655

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution was to create a custom **CakePHP Test suite** which adds specific files/directories to be tested, then run that suite with the command `cake test app AllTests`.

For example, here is my `Test/Case/AllTests.php`:

```
/*
 * Custom test suite to execute all tests
 */

class AllTestsTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite {

    public static function suite() {

        $path = APP . 'Test' . DS . 'Case' . DS;

        $suite = new CakeTestSuite('All tests');
        $suite->addTestDirectory($path . 'Model' . DS);
        return $suite;

    }

}
```

This testsuite simply adds the `Models` directory to the testing environment, so all my model tests now get executed. As you can see it can be extended to run more/all tests as seen fit.

Comment: If you get here through Google, you add *all* tests (not just those from Model dir) like this: `$suite->addTestDirectoryRecursive(TESTS . 'Case');`

Comment: i think more description is required ,i am not understanding the solution here, am i missing something

Answer (score 0):

Try `cake test app all`. I can't confirm this makes the difference just now, but I've pulled this out of a phing build file where I'm doing the same thing as you so it should be good.